# Matplotlib colorbar invisible with animation

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, colorbar

When I create a subplot in a figure for displaying an image with imshow, I add a colorbar. It is okay with no animation about this subplot.
But if I add an animation, the colorbar don't appear at the launch of the GUI (or each time I change the cmap of the colorbar). I have to click on another window (other software, etc) or resize the GUI to see the colorbar.

Here is an example to understand the problem :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib import animation

class FenetrePrincipale(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FenetrePrincipale, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    # Fonction de configuration de la classe
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.Form = Form

        Form.setMinimumSize(1220, 850)

        self.creation_GUI()
        self.creation_figure()
        self.creation_layout()

        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.Bouton_quitter.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animate, interval=10, blit=True)

    def animate(self, i):
        # a = self.thread_1.img
        self.image.set_array(self.imageInit)
        return [self.image]

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 60))

    def creation_GUI(self):
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "  Tab1  ")

        self.Widget_choixPalette_Label = QLabel(self.tab1)
        self.Widget_choixPalette_Label.setText("Text1")
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox = QComboBox(self.tab1)
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox.addItem("Try1")
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox.addItem("Try2")

        self.Bouton_quitter = QPushButton(self.tab1)
        self.Bouton_quitter.setText("Quit")

    def creation_layout(self):
        LayoutForm = QGridLayout(self)
        LayoutForm.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        LayoutTab1 = QGridLayout(self.tab1)

        LayoutTab1.addWidget(self.Widget_choixPalette_Label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        LayoutTab1.addWidget(self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Widget_choixPalette_ComboBox.setMinimumWidth(200)

        LayoutTab1.addWidget(self.canvas, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        LayoutTab1.addWidget(self.Bouton_quitter, 2, 3, 1, 1, Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

        LayoutTab1.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        LayoutTab1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        LayoutTab1.setColumnStretch(2, 1)

    def creation_figure(self):
        # Create figure (transparent background)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        # self.figure.patch.set_facecolor('None')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")

        # Adding one subplot for image
        self.axe0 = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axe0.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.axe0.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

        # Data for init image
        self.imageInit = [[255] * 320 for i in range(240)]
        self.imageInit[0][0] = 0

        # Init image and add colorbar
        self.image = self.axe0.imshow(self.imageInit, interpolation='none')
        divider = make_axes_locatable(self.axe0)
        cax = divider.new_vertical(size="5%", pad=0.05, pack_start=True)
        self.colorbar = self.figure.add_axes(cax)
        self.figure.colorbar(self.image, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')

        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0.05, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)

        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("plastique"))
    form = FenetrePrincipale()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With animation :
[image]

Setting lines of animation in comment :
[image]

Matplotlib version

- Operating system: Windows 7 Pro
- Matplotlib version: 2.0.2
- Matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg
- Python version: 3.6

Comment: You could explain the error better, show an image of what you get and what you want to get.

Comment: I added two images which show the colorbar invisible in first when I have animation to refresh the image, and colorbar visible when I have no animation.

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you have? the current version is '2.1.0', Where did you get version 4.0.4? :P

Comment: It is 2.0.2 ^.^ My mistake

Comment: I have tried it in version 2.1.0 and it works correctly, I recommend you update them, maybe in an old version like yours have that problem.

Comment: Ok so it is true that it is working with 2.1.0 for this bug at the start of the GUI. But now I have always the same problem when I change the cmap during the animation. I modify my example like this you can see, if you change in the combobox the choice, the colormap is change but the colorbar disappear.

Comment: That's another problem, every post is by question, not by project. I would recommend you to restore the previous question, post a response and mark it as correct and then create a new question!!!!

Comment: Ok then can you post the answer with the version of matplotlib? I can't accept my own response. I create a new topic for this other problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955413/colorbar-disappear-during-animation-of-image-when-changing-colormap)

Comment: No, publish it with the version you currently have.

Comment: You can accept your own answer but must spend a minimum time, tomorrow you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the version of matplotlib.
With 2.0.2 it is not working, but with the last one (2.1.0), there is no more problem.